# How to transfer post data using router in expressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to ExpressJS and Node. I am trying to transfer post data to main.js from index.js. Below are the codes

index.js

```
var express=require('Express');
var app=express();
var things=require('./things.js');
var main=require("./main.js");
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var multer=require('multer');
var upload=multer();

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(upload.array());
app.set("view engine","pug");
app.set("views","./views");
app.use("/login",main);
app.use("/things",things);

app.listen(2000);
```

main.js

```
var express=require("express");
var router=express.Router();
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var multer=require('multer');
var upload=multer();
var app=express()

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(upload.array());
app.set("view engine","pug");
app.set("views","./views");

router.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("login");
});

router.post("/",function(req,res){
     console.log("Came to post");
     console.log(req.body);
     res.send("received");
 });
module.exports=router;
```

login.pug

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    title Login
  body
    form(action='/', method='POST')
      label(for='email') Email: 
      input#email(type='text')


      button Login
```

I have tried the above and after submitting email I get "cannot POST /"

I have tried it without using router and writing all get and post code in index.js and it works fine but not while using router.

Comment: Can you change the request url to '/login'

Comment: I have changed it and the request is going but in console.log(req.body),empty json is viewed {}. and in webpage I change the code in main.js(router.post) to var data=req.body; res.send("received"+data.email) but it shows received undefined.

Comment: I am just trying from basic only

Answer (score 0):

In login.pug file make the required change,

```
form(action='/login', method='POST')
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but the req.body is not receiving email input. It is showing {} in console.
I have also changed to var data=req.body; res.send("received "+data.email);
In web page it shows received undefined

Comment: Can you post ur js file where ur ajax call is occuring?

Comment: Above mentioned is the current code which I have currently, with only change is to main.js and as you mention in form action to '/login'  
router.post("/",function(req,res){
     console.log("Came to post");
     var data=req.body;
     res.send("received "+data.email);
 });

Comment: Iam talking about the client side js where u will be send the body?